# Is there any way in which a chrome extension can access a local file?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesystems, chromium

I've tried many things to read a local file from an extension's background script. Adding `file://*` (and even `*://*`) to the `permissions` list didn't work because XMLHttpRequest refuses to work with anything but http.

So, is there a way to access local files without resorting to native client or a small proxy server?

edit: Just to be clear, the file I want to access is located outside the extension's directory.

Comment: You could use iframes and content scripts for text/css/javascript/... files.

Comment: @RobW chrome refuses to load local resources via iframe (regardless of permissions, it seems).

Comment: If you load a local page, that page can be used to open local files, and with the `file:///*` permission, you'll be able to access it. Other options are a proxy server or a NPAPI plugin (that's a big hammer though).

Comment: May I ask how? loading the local file/page via iframe inside a background page causes the error message: `... has a protocol of 'chrome-extension', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'file'. Protocols must match.`. As far as I can tell from the documentation, `contentSecurityPolicy` can't be relaxed for `file://*` urls.

Comment: The user would have to open (e.g. via a bookmark) a local file (e.g. `file:///home/rob/launch.htm`). Then, a content script can communicate between the local page and the extension.